# How to add "Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types." Notification in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, notification, notice

Hello Everyone I have created a module the save changes only works when the cache is a refresh to I want to add a Notice on Save to Refresh Cache Something like that.

How I can do this Need help

[image]

Comment: In every page ?

Comment: Yes in Admin Side when he saves an item

Comment: Hello, I have an idea about that,
Can you please contact me skype I help you on that.
live:tusharlathiya1996

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the class `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface` and `Magento\PageCache\Model\Config` in your save controller like below.

```
class Save
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $typeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $typeList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $typeList
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->typeList = $typeList;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** Your Save code Here */
        $this->typeList->invalidate(
                \Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER
            );
    }

}
```

This code will invalidate the FPC and show the notification after saves details from your module.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface` and use method `invalidate`

Example:

```
<?php

namespace Y;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config;

class X 
{
    private $cacheTypeList;

    public function __construct(TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList)
    {
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
        $this->cacheTypeList->invalidate(Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);  
    }
}
```

In the example above, you'll invalidate `config` cache type